# dbDelta SQL Query Not Working

Tags: plugin-development, database

I know the specifics of using dbDelta and I've read the documentation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), read other answers to the question I'm asking, but I'm just not seeing what I'm doing wrong. When I var_dump the result of dbDelta, I get no errors, just "`array(1) { [0]=> string(48) "Added index wp_ovrdrvamdata PRIMARY KEY id (id)" }`" or some other untrue statement. The table just is not being created.

Here is the code/query:

```
function ovrdrv_asset_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $ovrdrv_am_db_version;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $data_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ovrdrvamdata';


    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ". $data_table_name ." (
            id int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            data varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            form_id smallint(4) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  id (id)
        );";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    var_dump(dbDelta( $sql ));
    $wpdb->print_error();
    add_option('ovrdrv_am_db_version', $ovrdrv_am_db_version);
}
```

EDIT: After turning on WPDB errors, I'm getting these errors:

```
WordPress database error: [Multiple primary key defined]
ALTER TABLE wp_ovrdrvamdata ADD PRIMARY KEY id (id) /* From             [client.staging.wpengine.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?activate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=] in [/nas/wp/www/staging/client/wp-content/plugins/client-plugin/table-creation.php:22] */
array(1) { [0]=> string(48) "Added index wp_ovrdrvamdata PRIMARY KEY id (id)" }

WordPress database error: [Multiple primary key defined]
ALTER TABLE wp_ovrdrvamdata ADD PRIMARY KEY id (id) /* From [client.staging.wpengine.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?activate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=] in [/nas/wp/www/staging/client/wp-content/plugins/client-plugin/table-creation.php:22] */
```

It seems as if it's trying to add the primary key multiple times or something, even though the table does not exist yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post more complete code so we can see what the surrounding code is doing. We have no idea what $data_table_name is here, or how you're using that SQL in the context of the plugin.

Comment: More code has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is invalid.

`PRIMARY KEY  id (id)`

Should just be:

`PRIMARY KEY  (id)`

Unlike other KEYs, PRIMARY KEYs don't have identifiers or names. They don't need them, because you can only have one.

Comment: Thanks, good eye. I copied and pasted code from the documentation and didn't even think to change that, as the documentation has UNIQUE KEY instead of PRIMARY KEY. Lesson learned.

Comment: Thanks to this answer. The double space after the word `PRIMARY KEY` is necessary to prevent error "WordPress database error Multiple primary key defined for query ALTER TABLE".

Answer (score 1):

If you're throwing an error on your SQL statement, you should refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors for advice on how to identify it.  It's not always apparently obvious that an error has occurred if you don't go looking for it.

Comment: Yeah, I got some errors, but they don't make sense to me. Check it out.